# How do I Multiply unit price and quantity for total price?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have inputs like this -

```
<div id="multipleEntry">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <table class="table table-borderless">
                <tbody>
                    <td>
                        <x-layouts.dropdowns name="product_id[]" title="Product" class="mt-2" id="productName" :dropItems="$products" :setItem="old('productName')" option1="Select Product" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <x-layouts.input name="unitPrice[]" title="Unit Price" type="number" id="unitPrice" :value="111" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <x-layouts.input name="quantity[]" title="Quantity" type="number" id="quantity" :value="old('quantity')" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <x-layouts.input name="price[]" title="Price" type="number" id="price" :value="old('price')" />
                    </td>
                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 mb-3" id="controls">
        <button class="btn btn-primary addNewBtn" type="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
```

and for increment of columns I used -

```
const addNewBtn = document.querySelector(".addNewBtn");
const multipleEntry = document.querySelector("#multipleEntry");

addNewBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const lastRow = multipleEntry.lastElementChild;

    let clone = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
    multipleEntry.appendChild(clone);
});
```

I want to calculate the price and sub total price dynamically with javascript.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your js function:

```
const addNewBtn = document.querySelector(".addNewBtn");
const multipleEntry = document.querySelector("#multipleEntry");


addNewBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let quantityArr = [];
  let totalAmount = [];

const lastRow = multipleEntry.lastElementChild;

var length = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]').length;
var prices = document.getElementsByName('unitPrice[]');
var quantity = document.getElementsByName('quantity[]');

for (let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
  quantityArr.push(parseInt(quantity[i-1].value));
  totalAmount.push(parseInt(quantity[i-1].value) * parseInt(prices[i-1].value));      
}


console.log(totalAmount);
console.log(quantityArr);
let clone = lastRow.cloneNode(true);
multipleEntry.appendChild(clone);
});
```